# Program delay loop - tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to code a clickbot with Python and Tkinter.
The program starts, shows a window and there you can type in your display coordinates and submit the numbers. Than the program should click at these coordinates every 5 minutes.

Submitting the numbers and clicking on the right position works. But the loop every 5 mins not really. I don't have any more ideas.
I know, I can use `time.sleep()`, but then the entire program sleeps.

```
import time
import tkinter as tk
import time
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller

def getTextInput():
    global ValueX
    global ValueY
    resultX = e1.get()
    ValueX = resultX
    X = float(ValueX)
    resultY = e2.get()
    ValueY = resultY
    Y = float(ValueY)
    print('Eingabe X: ', X)
    print('Eingabe Y: ', Y)
    KlickMouse(X, Y)

def KlickMouse(X, Y):
    print('Old Mouse Pos:{0}'.format(mouse.position))
    mouse.position = (X, Y)
    time.sleep(0.2)
    # mouse.click(Button.left, 1)
    # time.sleep(0.2)
    # mouse.click(Button.left, 1)
    print('New Mouse Pos:{0}'.format(mouse.position))

mouse = Controller()
master = tk.Tk()
tk.Label(master, text="X-Koordinate").grid(row=0)
tk.Label(master, text="Y-Koordinate").grid(row=1)
tk.Button(master, text="Submit", command=getTextInput).grid(row=2)
tk.Button(master, text="Beenden", command=master.destroy).grid(row=3)
e1 = tk.Entry(master)
e2 = tk.Entry(master)
e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
e2.grid(row=1, column=1)
master.mainloop()
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `time.sleep(...)` when using `tkinter`. Look at `.after` scripts.

Comment: Here's some [documentation](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/universal.html) on the `after()` method.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Tkinter's `after` method to do this.

```
def KlickMouse(X, Y):
    print('Old Mouse Pos:{0}'.format(mouse.position))
    mouse.position = (X, Y)
    print('New Mouse Pos:{0}'.format(mouse.position))
    master.after(5*60*1000, timedClick)

def timedClick():
    mouse.click(Button.left, 1)
    master.after(5*60*1000, timedClick)
```

Now after the coordinates have been set, the program waits 5 minutes (the delay is in milliseconds, so 5 minutes is `5*60*1000`) and runs `timedClick`. This clicks the mouse, then waits another 5 minutes before calling itself again.

Comment: You still have a `time.sleep` in there.

Comment: Yeah, I just left it in there in case they wanted it for some reason

Comment: It's still going to cause the GUI to lag. It's better to remove it.

Comment: Try splitting klickMouse to a 2 functions, and chain them with `after()`

Comment: @madbird What does that mean?

Comment: @Henry If you moved everything after the `time.sleep(0.2)` inside another function then used `.after(200, <that function>)`, it would have eliminated the need for the `time.sleep`

Comment: The `time.sleep` bit didn't do anything anyway, so I just removed it.

Comment: Calling `sleep()` in a tkinter app **does** do something, it blocks the `mainloop()` and make the app "hang".

Comment: What I meant by "it does nothing" is it serves no purpose. It wasn't necessary for the program to work properly and it wasn't needed in the solution so I removed it. I am fully aware of the effects of using `time.sleep` in a tkinter program, thank you.